# How to change the color of text values entered in the search field with a button?

Tags: javascript, html

With this code we can send several values to the search field with a single button, but how do we make these values appear in a color (for example green)?

http://jsfiddle.net/7bpaL5hy/

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
const myValues = ['Decoration', 'Health', 'Fun', 'Yesterday 4'];
let myInd = 0;

function setValue() {
    document.getElementById('bbb').value = myValues[myInd];
    myInd = myInd >= (myValues.length - 1) ? 0 : myInd+1;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in many ways but the best way is to be done with CSS. You just need that container id in which you are storing these values. Here, in your case, you have input tag with the id #bbb just use this and add whichever colour you want.

`#bbb{
color: green;
}`

You can also do this using JS but when things can be done with CSS then why to use JavaScript.

Check the snippet below.

```css
#bbb{
color: green;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
const myValues = ['Decoration', 'Health', 'Fun', 'Yesterday 4'];
let myInd = 0;

function setValue() {
    document.getElementById('bbb').value = myValues[myInd];
    myInd = myInd >= (myValues.length - 1) ? 0 : myInd+1;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the text color with js, like this:

Try it here, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/baomy5hr/
Or here, with font size and bold: http://jsfiddle.net/6s0zqf1a/

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
const myValues = ['Decoration', 'Health', 'Fun', 'Yesterday 4'];
let myInd = 0;

function setValue() {
    document.getElementById('bbb').value = myValues[myInd];
    myInd = myInd >= (myValues.length - 1) ? 0 : myInd+1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bbb').css({'color':'green'});    
});
}

</script>
```